# Completely remove bars with 0 values

Tags: chart.js

I'm using charts.js 2.9.4

I can render the chart just fine as you can see in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq647k3f/7/)

```js
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';

var ctx = document.getElementById("data");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Data 1",
        backgroundColor: "#198754",
        borderWidth: "0",
        data: [1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      },
      {
        label: "Data 2",
        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
        borderWidth: "0",
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000],
      },
      {
        label: "Data 3",
        backgroundColor: "#6f42c1",
        borderWidth: "0",
        data: [650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650],
      },
      {
        label: "Data 4",
        backgroundColor: "#ffc107",
        data: [350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: function(context) {
          return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 1;
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Points',
      fontSize: '20',
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'Gal'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 10,
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          suggestedMin: 0,
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 1000,
          maxTicksLimit: 10,
          beginAtZero: true,
          suggestedMin: 0
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  }
});
```

As you can see the 0 values already doesn't show anything, but there are gaps.

What I wanted to do is completely remove those gaps. I've search and tried different options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186169/remove-0s-zeros-from-x-axis-of-bar-chart-in-chart-js) and also tried [this](https://v1_0_0--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html) but nothing seem to work.

Is it even doable?

Any help?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just parse the data and drop all 0s?